# How to configure webpack and tsconfig to resolve module outside app directory

Tags: webpack, jhipster, typescript2.0, typescript-compiler-api

I created an angular 4 app using jhipster generator and used gradle as build tool. jhipster is using webpack as module bundler.

I need to create a directory outside jhipster app 'SharedDir' and implement some modules and components there

```
jhipsterApp/
            src/
               main/
            ...
SharedDir/
         Shared.module.ts
```

the problem is when I import `Shared.module.ts` in `app.module.ts` I got TS error "Cannot Resolve 'SharedModule'".

How do I configure webpack and tsconfig to resolve SharedModule correctly?

.yo.rc

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.6.2",
    "baseName": "app",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": true,
    "jwtSecretKey": "fa94269e1436946e56119fe5c97977279cbdbc1e",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "ar-ly",
      "fr"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.ts

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "build/www/app",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/main/webapp/app",
        "src/test/javascript/"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "src/main/webapp/app/app.main-aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you considered creating an npm module for your shared code in its own folder and referring to it using JHipster app package.json? [ng-jhipster lib](https://github.com/jhipster/ng-jhipster) could be a good example.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou So you mean that Shared code should be an app too ( that contains package.json and node_modules dir) and using 'yarn link' to link with the app?

Comment: It depends whether your shared code contains html or not, fi it does yes you could have an angular app to test it visually, otherwise it could be a library like ng-jhipster. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1692 has some good insights. Yarn link is just an easy way for developing/debugging